# How to remove buildings

Tags: black-and-white

I have an extra workshop that I accidentally built. Its taking up room I'd rather use for housing. How can I completely remove a building?

Comment: I've got the sudden urge to play Black and White once again. Good bye, social life...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If construction hasn't started, you can pick up the scaffolding and place it somewhere else.

If the building has been built, the easiest way to remove it is to burn it down completely. Drop a fireball on the building (it's the safest way to set it on fire) and wait. This may take a few attempts as villagers will often try to extinguish it. Try not to hit too many of them.

The megablast miracle can completely remove any building if you have access to it.

Comment: Ah, no "please gently demolish this building" labour or command, then. Well then, fire it is!

Comment: Wait, dropping a fireball is the safest way to remove a building? What's the least safe way?

Comment: @TheUgly *Throwing* the fireball?

Comment: I should probably make sure my very impressionable creature is far away and busy while I torch the friendly village too, eh?

Comment: "I'm going to burn down this building..." *villagers extinguish it*  "I'm going to burn down these villagers" *creature comes along* "YAY FIRE" *creature burns down village*